# AWS Glue: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above [Using CockroachDB]

Tags: amazon-web-services, psycopg2, aws-glue, cockroachdb, libpq

I have a glue job using psycopg2 that was previously working, and now is throwing this error: `OperationalError: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`.

Here is the psycopg2 version and libpq version:

```
2.9.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)
90224
```

This job was previously running on glue and started failing. It appears I need to upgrade my libpq version, but I have found nothing documenting how to do this in AWS Glue. This is not a python library, but rather a c library that psycopg2 depends on.

Answer (score 2):

Add job parameter, will help to resolve the connection issue. AWS Glue will get binary from pip3.

```
--additional-python-modules : psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue controls the version of `libpq`, you cannot upgrade this. Even when upgrading to `psycopg2===2.9.6`. The version is still locked to version 9.x. After opening a support ticket with AWS, they confirmed that Glue does not allow SCRAM auth via python code today.

Reason for the error: upgrading CockroachDB to version 22.2.x, these changes included default encryption change from `bcrypt`, to `scram-sha-256`. Additionally, existing passwords were migrated to scram. After contacting CockroachDB, the recommended solution was to downgrade from `scram` to `bcrypt`.

You need to set these cluster fields to revert back:
`server.user_login.downgrade_scram_stored_passwords_to_bcrypt.enabled`
`server.user_login.password_encryption`